# PDF JavaScript: Function with a loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, pdf

Can anyone please let me know what is wrong with my code below? I am trying to create function with a loop, for hiding and making visible labels in the PDF document depending on the user selections.

My original code:

```js
if ((type == "sugar") && (countryofgrowth == "United State"))
{
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.visible;
       getField("goodsugar").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
}
else if ((type == "sugar") && (countryofgrowth == "United Kingdom"))
{
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;   
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;          
 }
```

Function with a loop:

```js
var setDisplay = function(display){
  var fields = ["sugarlabel", "goodsugar", "sugarQualitylevellow" /*,...*/];
    for(var i=0; i< fields.length; i++){
      if(fields[i] == display) {
          getField(fields[i]).display=display.visible;
        } else {
          getField(fields[i]).display=display.hidden;
        }
    }
}
if ((type == "sugar") && (countryofgrowth == "United State"))
{ 
setDisplay("sugarlabel")
}
```

I am keep getting an error: `'RangeError: Invalid argument value.`

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To which line does the error message refer?

It is not very smart to use a variable name which is also a property of an object. So, instead of the variable "display" I suggest to use something else.

It is also better to define a function independent of any variable, and as it may be used frequently, as document-level script. The function could look like this:

```
function setDisplay(item)
{
        var fields = ["sugarlabel", "goodsugar", "sugarQualitylevellow" /*,...*/];
    for(var i=0; i< fields.length; i++){
            if(fields[i] == item) {
                this.getField(fields[i]).display=display.visible;
        } else {
                getField(fields[i]).display=display.hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

When you call it, you can proceed as you have (although again, using "type" as a variable name is suboptimal.

On the other hand, I don't see why a function would bring advantages over a direct command. You may gain more by using some smart hierarchical field naming, which would allow to hide all fields concerned and then show what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats solved my error, however, it does not work fully, as I did not think that at same stage I need to be able to disply more than one label, and above code only displays one of them. Wouls you please post example of your idea about "smart hierarchical field naming", I will have that a go to see if it will work for me

Comment: "smart hierarchical field naming"… smart stands for "well thought out", and has nothing to do with software or so. "hierarchical field naming" in PDF is grouping field names by using the period "." as a separator, such as in "name.first", "name.middle", "name.last". For certain properties, you can access the group via this.getField("name"), and, for example, hide the whole group in one single command.

Comment: Thank you Max. Would you be also able to suggest how I can modify my function, so it returns multiple values, i.e. If I want to display 'setDisplay("sugarlabel")' & 'setDisplay("goodsugar")'? Currenlty irrespective of number of fields I set to display it only returns one.